# How To Parse XML Files Using JQuery To Update A HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, ajax

I need to parse XML files that will be a certain format and then work out whether the home or away team has won and then allocate 3 or 1 points to a HTML table (Overall Points Column) determined by the result, I would prefer to use JQuery to do this.

results.xml Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<title>Results</title>
  <results>
    <result id="1234">
      <hometeam>
        <name>Roma</name>
        <score>2</score>
      </hometeam>
      <awayteam>
        <name>Lazio</name>
        <score>0</score>
      </awayteam>
  </result>
</results>
```

HTML Code:

```
<table id="table">
<th>Team</th>
<th>Played</th>
<th>Won</th>
<th>Drawn</th>
<th>Lost</th>
<th>Total Goals</th>
<th>Overall Points</th>

<tr>
<td>Roma</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Lazio</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Inter</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Milan</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JQuery Code:

```
function showData() {
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "results.xml",
dataType: "xml",
```

This is all I have so far for the JQuery code.

Where would the calculation to work out the result go?

```
if (hometeam score > awayteam score)
{ add 3 to hometeams Overall Points}
else if (hometeam score = awayteam score)
{ add 1 to hometeams Overall Points and add 1 to awayteams Overall Points}
else 
{ add 3 to awayteams Overall Points}
```

How would I evaluate the hometeam and awayteam score and update the correct team in the HTML table?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could use javascript to parse xml such as with jQuery's parseXML function. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

However, this could be slow because you must parse a large file every time an end-user goes to your page. XML files tend to be hefty.

I would instead convert the XML to either JSON or database rows first.

PHP has a library called Simple XML Parser that comes with most distributions. The interface is really straightforward. Python also has a rich library called lxml to parse XML.

Of course, if you really want to parse XML with javascript, this question is helpful I think.
[Paging Through XML Data Using jQuery and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513567/paging-through-xml-data-using-jquery-and-html)

Answer (score 0):

When you compare your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "results.xml",
dataType: "xml",
```

to the example in the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you see what's missing.
Here is what your call could look like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "results.xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  type: "GET",
  success: function(data){
    // do something with data
  }
});
```

you need to specify a function that will be called if the data is successfully returned.
In the example above the function is an anonymous function. you could also use a normal function
with a name:

```
function handle_success(data){
    // do something with data
}

$.ajax({
  url: "results.xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  type: "GET",
  success: handle_success
});
```

But beware the A in AJAX: it stands for asynchronous. which means:
your success-function will be called a lot later, or even never.
the rest of your program continues on as usual after the ajax-call.